# In java, can i use string split to split by character?

Tags: java, split

For instance, I have the String variable `abbaabbbba`. I would like to use String split so each character would be separated, so it would be `{a,b,b,a,a,b,b,b,b,a}`. All the instructions I can find for string split say i need to have something, like a a space:

`String mySplit = str.split("/");`

Is there anyway to do this by character?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the toCharArray method like this:

```
String myString = "abbaabbbba";
char[] myCharacters = myString.toCharArray();
```